# Custom Horizontal(More like circular) Table View

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

Could anyone lead me in the right direction to build something like the following image? Specifically the bottom part where the contact images appear.

[image]

How could I make the table view horizontal and have an arc?
Looking for answers for both ios and android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great library out there for this on iOS: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Inverted wheel is what you want, you'll need to tweak it a little but that is easily achieved by looking at the demo project.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you on the Android side:

Basically, you get some images from artwork, then you write code with some trigonometry in it.

This will get you started: [android-rotaryknob-view](https://code.google.com/p/android-rotaryknob-view/)

There is a link at the bottom with more detailed code and explanation.